# Rails Mysql to Postgresql Float

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql

I'm transferring my database from mysql to postgresql.

I have a latitude and longitude column for one of my models:

```
  t.float :latitude
  t.float :longitude
```

I'm using mysql2psql gem to load the mysql database into a postgres database locally.

The problem I have is after I transferred the mysql database to postgres I have data such as:

Latitude: 40
Longitude: -83

Rather than:

Latitude: 40.xxxx
Longitude -83.xxxx

Please advise.

Mysql:

```
+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| latitude               | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude              | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

Comment: Is there a way to check from pgadmin?

Comment: psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"? I get this without using the admin tool, but that's another issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know pgadmin, I prefer to do things by hand.

Comment: It seems the latitude value is double precision. When I use mysql2psql it converts it to numeric.

Comment: Are you sure about that `numeric`? A quick review of the [source code](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres/blob/master/lib/mysql2psql/mysql_reader.rb#L53) suggests that a MySQL `float` should be converted to `double precision` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: yes, I ran rake db:migrate to setup the db and it's double precision. After I ran mysql2psql  it's numeric.

Comment: I only see one instance of "numeric" in the [source code](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres) and that wouldn't be used here. Sorry, none of this makes any sense to me, look for logging options to extract more information about the transfer process or report a bug to the gem's author.